Theoretical pricing models as time to expiry approaches
I was reading Option pricing and volatility by Sheldon Natenburg and in chapter 5 he says the following:
“Although traders typically express time to expiration in days, a trader may want to use a different measure. Especially as expiration approaches, a trader may prefer to use hours or even minutes. In theory, finer time increments should yield more accurate values. But there is a practical limitation to using very small increments of time. As time passes, the discrete increments of time we feed into a theoretical pricing model may not accurately represent the continuous passage of time in the real world. Most traders have learned through experience that as expiration approaches, the use of a theoretical pricing model becomes less reliable because the inputs become less reliable. Indeed, very close to expiration, many traders stop using model-generated values altogether.”
What does he mean by "discrete increments of time we feed into a theoretical pricing model may not accurately represent the continuous passage of time in the real world"
Does he mean that if time to expiry is very less, any kind of discrete time step we take to calculate the our parameters(the author mentions price changes which I guess means volatility?), it is not good enough to model the infinitesimal scale we should ideally look at?

He is not very clear. My opinion: Yes, if the time is very short (a few hours) it becomes difficult to predict the volatility until maturity. Due to exogenous events, the vol could change quite drastically at that time scale. Your input to the theoretical model is only a wild guess. (Other mathematical assumptions (lognormality, independent increments, continuity) also come under question at a short time scale).

This writing is a bit odd. When I calculate an expectation, I don't feed any discrete increments of anything anywhere.
